# Passing an @Observable view model variable as a @Binding parameter generates an error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view that requires a binding array

```
struct CustomHabitSwipeView: View {
    // Passed Variables
    @Binding var unCompletedHabits: [Habit]
    @Binding var completedHabits: [Habit]
```

Thing is though, that whenever I pass `completedHabits` from the `viewModel`

```
completedHabits: $vm.completedHabits
```

It generates an error

```
Cannot find '$vm' in scope
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show how you declare your `vm` and pass it to your `CustomHabitSwipeView` since this is where you say the problem is.